# POSTFIX header checks with TO and FROM conditions

Tags: postfix-mta

I would like to add a new action in the headers check file of my postfix server with 2 conditions: FROM and TO at the same time.

I already have a few lines checking the FROM or the SUBJECT like this:

```
/^FROM:.*user@domain.com/ REDIRECT special@mydomain.com
```

This rule works fine, but redirects all mail from **user@domain.com** to the **special@mydomain.com**

The thing is that I need the redirect only if the **TO** was a given mailbox, not all.

> THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but that's not possible.

```
Each message header or message body line is compared against a list  of
patterns.   When a match is found the corresponding action is executed,
and the matching process is repeated for the  next  message  header  or
message body line.
```

Meaning, you can check the To: header and you can check the From: headerm but not at the same time.